# The problem of calling “MKL pardiso” in Julia

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl, pardiso

### Background：

- I have a large sparse matrix written by `Julia` that requires solutions, and I want to use `MKL pardiso` to improve speed.
- I've found the [pardiso.jl](https://github.com/JuliaSparse/Pardiso.jl#mkl-pardiso) page and read README.

### What I've done：

- Install Pardiso in Julia:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("Pardiso")
```

---

- Download MKL:

  As I understand it, MKL pardiso is included in the MKL library.So I download from [web](https://software.seek.intel.com/performance-libraries).

  After registering, I received an email with a download link. On the download page, I chose `Intel math kernel library for windows`.

  Then I got the documents:`w_mkl_2019.4.245.exe`,I installed it completely on the computer.

---

- Build `Pardiso.jl`:

```
Pkg. build ("Pardiso")

julia> using Pardiso
┌ Warning: No Pardiso library found when Pkg.build("Pardiso") ran, this package will not currently be usable. See the installation instructions and rerun Pkg.build("Pardiso").
└ @ Pardiso C:\Users\huoze\.julia\packages\Pardiso\66TFF\src\Pardiso.jl:105
```

### Question:

As mentioned above, I made a mistake in Julia. I think my MKL did not configure environment variables correctly, but I don't know how to do this step.

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.1.1
Commit 55e36cc308 (2019-05-16 04:10 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.1 (ORCJIT, ivybridge)
```

(Or do I have other mistakes that I haven't found?)

Please tell me how to do about this?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/JuliaComputing/MKL.jl?

Comment: Since my main purpose is to use `MKL pardiso` to solve the equation, I am not sure that `MKL.jl` library can solve my problem, but `Pardiso.jl` I believe it meets my requirements.

Comment: I see, I was hoping `MKL.jl` can install MKL including MKL Pardiso and `pardiso.jl` will just use it once installed.

Comment: Following your prompt, I installed MKL.jl. Unfortunately, after the installation, Julia still prompted:
```julia
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.
```
When installing `MKL.jl`, I have added the system variable path of `mkl_intel_thread.dll`,Worse, my Julia can't start now...

Comment: `MKL.jl` says you have to reinstall julia to go back to the original state, sorry about it